# Ubuntu 22.04 Xinput settings partially changing when change with ~/.profile file

Tags: ubuntu, x11, ubuntu-22.04, xinput, trackball

This type of questions are all over the stackoverflow. I know it and I've searching this for almost 2 days. I started to look xinput configs that needed for my trackball. Than I found and configured but when I restart the PC, poof nothing persist. So I searched for hours and hours I tried nearly 25 combination and I come up with last resort, ~/.profile file. The only working solution is for me. But when I added my 2 configs like below, Sensitivity works like charm and Acceleration is not doing anything. if I would mistype something the desktop crashes and it don't let me to DE. So I have no errors showing but also always same -0.7.. accel value.

```
id=$(xinput | sed -nE 's/.*Kensington Eagle Trackball.*id=([0-9]+).*pointer.*/\>

xinput set-prop  $id  "libinput Accel Speed" 0.9
xinput set-prop  $id "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0.3 0 0 0 0.3 0 0 0 1
```

Why is my code works only half I want to know and solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out. Accel Speed is looks like same as the mouse speed under settings of ubuntu. I changed from settings and it also changed on xinput list. To me the command was working but settings was override it. On the other hand its a real shame that there is no setting for transformation matrix. Acceleration and mouse speed is different things and I believe it is not make sense.